# Homebrew wont install after migrating to a new Mac

Tags: git, installation, homebrew, apple-m1

I am getting this error message:

```
/bin/bash: line 234: /usr/local/bin/git: Bad CPU type in executable
Failed during: git init -q
```

What should I do ?

I tried to uninstall but it didn't work.

Comment: This is a generic mac-M1 issue, not a Git issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this article](https://linuxpip.org/fix-bad-cpu-type-in-executable/), this can happen because of:

> **Rosetta 2 not installed** – Apple M1 is an ARM-based chip, different from the Intel processors used in the prior devices. Software needs to be translated from x86 instructions to ARM via Rosetta 2 to be able to run on M1-based devices. Double check that Rosetta 2 is installed on your system.
>
> ```
> /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
> ```

This [discussion suggests](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1379#discussioncomment-672727):

> This suggests that you already have an Intel (via Rosetta 2) Homebrew installation, and you installed `git` there.
> Since you have `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH, the installer is using that `git`...and failing.
>
> Try this instead:
>
> - Open a new Terminal session.
> - Remove `/usr/local/bin` from `PATH` for this session:
>
>   PATH=${PATH//usr/local/bin:}
> - Run `which git curl` in this session. Confirm that you get no errors and neither path reported begins with `/usr/local/bin`
> - Run the installer (`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`) in this session.